# Why do these 3 greasemonkey (javascript) scripts conflict with each other?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

Ideally, I would like them all  running, but when I have the second and/or third one active, Script 1 fails. (It just does nothing)

I wonder, is it possible to merge them into one script? Would that solve the problem? (I am tempted to try cutting and pasting them into one script just to see what happens)

### Script 1 (the reloader)

```
(function () {
"use strict";

function walkTheDOM(node, func) {
    if (node && node.nodeType) {
        if (typeof func === "function") {
            func(node);
        }

        node = node.firstChild;
        while (node) {
            walkTheDOM(node, func);
            node = node.nextSibling;
        }
    }
}

function filterElementsByContains(elements, string) {
    var toStringFN = {}.toString,
        text = toStringFN.call(elements),
        result,
        length,
        i,
        element;

    if (text !== "[object NodeList]" && text !== "[object Array]" && !($() instanceof jQuery)) {
        return result;
    }

    result = [];
    if (typeof string === "string") {
        string = new RegExp("^" + string + "$");
    } else if (toStringFN.call(string) !== "[object RegExp]") {
        return result;
    }

    function getText(node) {
        if (node.nodeType === 3) {
            text += node.nodeValue;
        }
    }

    length = elements.length;
    i = 0;
    while (i < length) {
        text = "";
        element = elements[i];
        walkTheDOM(element, getText);
        if (string.test(text)) {
            result.push(element);
        }

        i += 1;
    }

    return result;
}

if(!filterElementsByContains([document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0]], /We are proud to announce that the November discounts have been chosen/).length) {
    location.reload();
}
}());
```

### Script 2 (Jump to last sheet, if it's multi sheet)

```
function getPreviousLink(){
var nextLink = document.getElementById('pagination-next-link'); 
var links = document.getElementsByClassName('v_page_nav')[0].getElementsByTagName("a");

for(var i=0; i < links.length; i++){
    if(links[i] == nextLink) { return links[i-1]; }
}
}

var link = getPreviousLink();
link.target="_blank";
link.click();
```

### Script 3 (open previous sheet, if there is one)

```
var link = document.getElementById('pagination-prev-link');
link.target="_blank";
link.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

If the second 2 scripts aren't changing anything that would cause your first script to break (like something the first script looks for gets removed by script 2)....  I would suggest going into 'manage scripts' and changing the order they run in... sometimes that can fix issues like this.